# Why does Google use conflicting character encoding on its homepage?

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding

I've been doing some research on declaring character encodings, and thought I'd look at what google do on their homepage.

On the google homepage `<head>` tags they have:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

But then in the `http headers` it's:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I'm interested in understanding they would do this.

Edit: It happens on `https://google.com/` I'm certain I spotted this in the browser earlier, but now I get the expected `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. However, when I send a request from `postman` I get the same http header as before.

It appears that the response is based on the `user-agent` request header. If I send a request with a missing or unusual `user-agent` the response header is `ISO-8859-1`. Still not sure why this is done and would be interested in an explanation.

Comment: Which page? On which language? Do you have a proxy? I checked on my computer (and google.com, and I get the expected `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi `https://google.com/` no proxy, in english. I've updated the question with extra infomation.